# Does react native app crashes if your backend APIs are not HTTPS or what is the possible reason of react native app crash?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, mobile, google-play

I have deployed my app on playstore and it deployed successfully. Now the problem is when i install it and try to open. it crashes immediately. I have checked the logs on playstore console. And the following logs in coming.

**Largest crash cluster**

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
```

**java.lang.RuntimeException**

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException (DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:20)
  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException (DisabledDevSupportManager.java:195)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:629)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$1100 (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:47)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:647)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:240)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:351)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
Caused by com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException:
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
```

If you need any further details. Please tell me. I'll provide you those too.